# PayPal Amount can only be increased by 20%

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

First of all, I found many topics similar to mine. But actually I didn't see any answers for this. So, here is my problem.

I have 2 types of monthly plans:

- Normal - 100 USD
- Premium - 200 USD

I create Subscription button via Button Creating Tool from merchant account. 
Now I want to allow my customers to be able to change their monthly subscription amount from 100 to 200 USD. Using the docs I found I can do this via adding the `modify` variable in my paypal form and setting it to `2`. But in this case customers will be able to increase their subscription amount just up to 20% in 180 days. Actually they can increase their subscriptions amount maximum to 120 USD not to 200 USD.

How I can allow my customers to set up more than 20% of subscription amount?

Answer (score 1):

The PayPal subscription feature was written about 15 years ago and hasn't been updated much since. Instead, PayPal has created several replacement products over the years.

This may not have been the best strategy for their customers, but it's what they did, so... your solution is to switch to one of their newer products.

Also, in their defense, one of the core features of the original subscriptions product is that it protects its consumer customers from merchants, and the inability of the merchant to suddently change the subscription price that they buyer showed at signup was part of that protection.

PayPal's newer products are more flexible for sellers but require that sellers be vetted to get access to these features (much as other payment processors vet sellers before letting them access customer credit/debit cards), unlike the original subscriptions product which is unvetted (any seller can use it).

So: if you want this flexibility, sign up for & use one of the newer "recurring payments" products.

Or: send your buyers through a new subscription signup (which shows them the new subscription amount) and cancel their old subscription.

Comment: The Recurring Payments API still has the 20% increase limit when working with Express Checkout, but not with Payments Pro.  The only way to avoid the limit when working with Express Checkout is to go with billing agreements / reference transactions instead, and then you would basically build your own recurring system to process the due payments every day.